# Getting error while publishing WAR file into JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss

[Server deployment][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpGLd.jpg

While deploying war file continuously getting error symbol on the deployed JRA. There was no compilation issue, all the projects are building successfully. while publishing/incremental publish getting the above error message.

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing?

Comment: The error attached in that image, not showing any error message.

Comment: You'd need to look at the logs. That's just a screen shot of Eclipse.